# Java Android: проблема с кодировкой при записи в файл

Tags: java, android, файлы, кодировка

Товарищи, беда, мучаюсь второй день.

Суть проблемы в том что если вызвать код

```
String txt = "Hello world";
try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path);
            fw.write(txt);
            fw.close();
        fw.close();} catch (Exception e){
        }
```

то в файл появляются иероглифы. Пишу в AndroidStudio. Если то же самое выполнить в Eclipse то всё замечательно записывается и читается. Пробовал ещё так:

```
BufferedWriter fw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(path, MODE_PRIVATE));
fw.write(txt);
fw.close();
```

вообще ни чего не записал. FileOutputStream - результат такой же как и в первом случае - иероглифы. Созданный файл открывал во всех кодировках, исходную строку так и не увидел. Хелп!

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так, с указанием кодировки.

```
// Вариант записи кодировки "UTF-8"
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path), "UTF-8"));
out.append(txt);
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Только что чекнул и в идее и в андроид студии, все работает. Путь задал вручную.

```
        String txt = "Hello world";
        try{
            FileWriter fw =
                    new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Documents\\java pro\\out.txt");
            fw.write(txt);
            fw.close();
            fw.close();} catch (Exception ignored){
        }
```